# XCTest test case failed with error "Failed to install or launch the test runner". (Underlying error: Could not connect to the device)

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, testcase, xctestcase

I am running an Xcode test command in the terminal. Here is the command

```
xcodebuild test -project $project_dir/Application.xcodeproj -scheme Application -sdk iphoneos -destination id=$UDID >> $LOGFILE_PATH
```

But my test case has failed with the error "Failed to install or launch the test runner. (Underlying error: Xcode encountered an error. Could not connect to the device)"

Attached is the screenshot for error log.[Screenshot for error log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17FAkqy4egEWVN1WEPhq_9TKZzwuTgPIe/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your screenshot is not attached.

Comment: Also, please let us know if you tried detaching and reattaching the device, etc.

Comment: @auspicious99 I have tested the device connectivity after the xcodebuild test command using "instruments -s devices" command , the device is shown as connected